# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust' error is not because of pip

Tags: python, rust, pip, setuptools, autopy

I'm trying to install `autopy`, but I get this error

```
Collecting autopy
  Using cached autopy-4.0.0.tar.gz (20 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\89651\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\89651\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\89651\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\89651\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2ctyo4gw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\89651\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2ctyo4gw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\89651\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2ctyo4gw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\89651\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2ctyo4gw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I googled it and found that this is because of outdated pip. But I have the latest version of pip and the note says that it's likely not a problem with pip. I also found that people get this error on versions of python above 3.8, but I didn't upgrade my python and it was working just fine. What do I do?

Comment: setuptools_rust is not a standard package. It sounds like the setup process for autopy does not download setuptools_rust, while it should.

Comment: The normal, binary installation fails, because there are no binary variants of the package for Python 3.11; thus, it needs to be built from source, which fails because of the above issue.

Comment: https://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy/issues , https://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy/issues?q=is%3Aissue+setuptools_rust

Comment: Note that autopy 4.0.0 is from 2020, so before Python 3.11 was released even. It looks like it hasn't really been updated since, so your problem is, in a way, having an old-ish package with a (too) new-ish Python.

Comment: You could try by installing setuptools-rust: `pip install setuptools-rust`. But with autopy being largely abondoned (last update about 4 years ago), you might consider using something else.

Comment: @9769953 Decent chance the Pip and/or Setuptools version would be problematic, too, since the modern expectation is that `setup.py` doesn't get run directly.

Comment: Anyway, please try following the installation instructions [in the README](https://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy#installation).

Comment: @9769953 Well, you wouldn't see `setuptools-rust` in the `setup.py` source code, because that isn't a valid identifier name. But you would see `from setuptools_rust import Binding, RustExtension` near the top, because `setuptools_rust` is the name of the Python module provided by that package ;) Many `setup.py` files tried to install requirements dynamically - including build-time requirements - by parsing a `requirements.txt` file like that, yes. But it would usually be too late for build-time requirements, because they're typically needed by `setup.py` *to be able to call `setup`*.

Comment: I have installed setuptools-rust already, that wasn't the case

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have installed the necessary prerequisites or not, but as you can see in the `autopy` [repository installation guide](https://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy?tab=readme-ov-file#installation), you have to:

1. Install the `rustup`
2. Install the nightly version of Rust 2019 (`nightly-2019-10-05`) through the`rustup`.
3. Install the `setuptools-rust` through the pip: `pip install -U setuptools-rust` (Take a look at the repository guide for further details).
4. Finally, you will be able to install the `autopy`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was running python with autopy in a different environment, where python version was 3.8, so it was working there, but not in python 3.11. Thank you all who answered